# Data binding issue with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, data-binding, vue.js

> target html with data binding

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <div class="row" v-for="test in tests">
     <div class="col-12">
        <router-link tag="a" :to="{ name:'test.index', params:{ id: test.id } }" >{{ test.name }}
        </router-link>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12">
         <img :src="(isTestURL && isPosted) ? '~/img/'+ 'testflow-img':'' + '.png'" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
   </div>
```

> Webpack mix config

```js
mix.webpackConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      masonry: "masonry-layout",
      isotope: "isotope-layout",
      // custom aliases for easy reference
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/assets/"),
      assets: path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/assets/assets/"),
      img: path.resolve(__dirname, "resources/assets/assets/img/")
    }
  },
```

I can see the result of `img/testflow-img.png`, and no rendering. Like this `example.com/img/testflow-img.png`.

> > /images/testflow-img.png?1a2086faf6b06b086b9f10c5cc50eae2

Please follow any suggestions.

Comment: Is the image really there?

Comment: What about src attribute in rendered img? Can you inspect it via devTools?

Comment: Can you be more concise on what are you trying to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your webpack config, your codeline is not available to render to `public\images` directory.

Maybe you'd use `v-if` instead of `Conditional operator` like this

```
<div class="col-12" v-if = "isTestURL && isPosted">
     <img :src="~/img/testflow-img.png" class="img-fluid" />
</div>
```

Comment: also, do resolve all img with importing assets, maybe it'll be work with you.